# Have there been any recent changes in the human verification policy?

Tags: support, captcha

I experience a very annoying evolution on Stack Overflow: I get the Captcha for every answer I post and it takes many trials to get through the validation process, to the point where it takes **longer** to pass the Captcha than it took to write the answer.  I experience the same difficulty with Chrome and Firefox and whether I use a home IP connection, a mobile one (both from France) or my business IP address.

I used to get a captcha only once in a while, but now I get it every time, in spite of my  135K reputation points.

Is there a recent change that can explain this behavior? or possibly a flag on my IP address(es)?

Comment: I keep many tabs (> 1000) with previous answers open in my Chrome browser... could this be the cause of the undesired behavior?

Comment: Not if your phone doesn't have >1000 tabs open and is connecting from a different connection

Comment: @KevinB: actually, I do not answer from my phone, I share its mobile connection with by macbook when I commute to work, so all the pending tabs might issue requests via the phone IP address...

Comment: if they're sharing the connection, then yes that'd put it in the same boat, if that's the cause

Comment: @KevinB: actually, SO probably does not see my mobile IP address as I use a VPN to my office network.  I shall investigate using different actual IP addresses

Comment: I underestimated the number of open tabs, it is closer to 2800 :)

Comment: I don't know about Chrome, but for Firefox, tabs are not activated/open until they are brought to the front (after a restart of Firefox). I have an ever-growing number of tabs, and they don't cause any trouble.

Comment: [There](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392328/) [have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393116/every-site-requesting-verification-that-im-human) [been a lot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393128/) [of reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393233/)  relatively recently.

Comment: There [is a cure](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/buster-captcha-solver-for/mpbjkejclgfgadiemmefgebjfooflfhl), as this extension can solve captchas for you. That's right! A robot completing the "I'm not a robot" check.

Comment: Wow. I've had occasions where I broke 100 tabs and felt like I was seriously drowning.

Comment: I guess [since the change to using CloudFlare on September 2023, the anti-bot checking has become more aggressive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393125/241919).

Comment: 2800 tabs open!? That kind of proves you're a machine right there.

Comment: 2800 tabs opened at the same time? How long has it been since the last time you turn off or restart your machine? Or are you using a server to browse SO?

Comment: @InSync: Chrome reloads all tabs for up to 24 separate windows when it restarts

Comment: @InSync: Chrome keeps the full history of every tab of every window a cross invocations. I actually migrated from an old mac to a newer one with a different OS and restored all these tabs... Call me Charlie the hoarder.